# Ubuntu freezes after login. After trying almost everything

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login

i spent the whole night with that issue, without a solution. I read almost every single post on google (google is completely violet already,  almost no links to click on any more). Yesterday i bought a brandnew laptop (with NVIDIA graphics, DELL Inspiron with GTX1050) and deleted Windows immediately. But after installing Linux (yeah, I was so happy when the Login screen was visible), the problems began. I had about 100 restarts already.

Immediately after the login Ubuntu freezes. The only way to get inside is by: Advanced options -> recovery mode -> network and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in the end. But this is not the solution i was searching for. I just want it to work normally. I really tried almost everything (I guess that I've installed a lot of unnecessary things..).

I read a lot about NVIDIA drivers, but I couldn't fix the problem anyway. Deleting, reinstalling, installing, deleting didn't help at all. If you have any idea, tell me and i will give you any information you need. Immediately. Holding my phone in my hand.

Comment: are you able to get to `tty2` by pressing `ctl`+`alt`+`F2` when it freezes?

Comment: in 18.04 doesn't f2 bring you to X? It seems I need to use f3 for it to work? sometimes my computer goes black screen on login, and cycling between ttys until I get back to X fixes it

Comment: crtl alt f2 doesnt work for me ;(

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: did you find any solution? if you did please tell me because I'm having the same issue and I tried everything.

Answer (score 3):

I had that problem for almost 4 days and I resolved it.

The problem is your gtx1050 driver (it can only work with the 390 or higher stable driver. Now the 390 is the highest).

step 1 : on your login page use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>" to access a terminal. (before typing a password use it the time you still not freeze).

step 2 : in terminal use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers`

step 3 : update the ppa you add `sudo apt-get update`

step 4 : install the latest nvidia driver `sudo apt-get install nvidia-390`

step 5 : let the installation complete and then restart your pc and enjoy.

If that doesn't work do this:

step 1 : on your bootloader (when you want to click on ubuntu) use "E" key on your keyboard to access gnu grub

step 2 : one line before end you see ...quiet spalsh "$vt_handoff" change it to "... quiet splash nomodeset" and press f10 (I guess) to boot (read the bottom of the grub page)

step 3 : after that you can access to ubuntu and login with no freeze

step 4  : install the geforce driver from the terminal like I said before and restart again

Comment: hey, thanks for the immediate answer, but: i tried to sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers, apt-update, install nvidia 390 and 396 many time tonight. i felt like i checked half of the internet :|. alt+ctrl+f2 doesnt work for me at all on the login page (is there another combination ?). i tried nomodeset as well. i could enter the system but the whole nvidia thing didnt work at all. i really feel like i tried everything. maybe there is something i have to delete before ? is there an option to delete everything i installed in the last 10 hours ?

Comment: and nomodeset doesnt work any more: error: mvlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic6'  not found. error: you need to load the kernel first.

Comment: but like i said: i can enter the system by using recovery mode and using network mode. afterwards i press ctrl + c and im inside. after rebboting i have to repeat the procedure in order to use it :(

Comment: the error you mentioned (you need to load the kernel firs) is because the way you install the linux .

Comment: what kind of partitions are you using ? did you creat a root and home seperately?

Comment: and witch version of ubuntu are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here on GeForce MX150 and driver 430, the solution I'm using and it's working like a charm is keep using kernel 4.18, if I forget to choose it and boot on kernel 5.0, sometimes it freezes before I can even reboot the notebook.

Comment: Yeah, booting from different kernel works for me. Go to advance ubuntu from grob then select a different kernel.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions listed here worked for me.

I could however use

```
ssh -X <user>@<host>
```

to start an X session from a different machine. (Fill your actual user, host obviously.)

Then do

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

and select Intel instead of nvidia.

Now I can get past the previous problem, but the resolution is miserably low, 960x540 at best. (Before the nvidia freezing misery I used to have a much higher resolution.)

Seems like a smaller problem, so I'll try to solve that next.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My graphics card is 950m (enough for some gaming). After I installed Nvidia drivers from Software&Update -> additional drivers, the issue started. What I did was writing the password very fast and going to additional drivers and change to nouveau drivers. If you cannot access recovery mode in any form then use a live usb ubuntu and create a partition than install in the new partition any OS so ubuntu will ask you during boot which one you want to choose and you can choose then recovery mode.